# After an external drag, resourceHeader become empty

Tags: reactjs, schedule, syncfusion

We need to drop an external item and then update the schedule data accordingly to that change by calling setState but resourceHeader become empty as their templates don't render as a consequence
I've reproduced the bug in this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gzetyr
and here also a recorded screenshot demo showing it: https://i.imgur.com/wjT9APb.gifv
PS: i had to call forceUpdate inside a setTimeout after the setState call because strangly setState call alone wasn't enough to re-render the schedule.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have validated the reported problem at our end and we suggest you to use the delayUpdate property to overcome the problem.

```
<ScheduleComponent ref={schedule => this.scheduleObj = schedule}  delayUpdate={true} > </ScheduleComponent>



<TreeViewComponent ref={tree => this.treeObj = tree} delayUpdate={true} </ TreeViewComponent>
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scheduler-i268259-external-drag-and-drop-utku7n?file=index.js

Kindly try the above sample and get in touch with us If you would need any further assistance.

UG link(delayUpdate): https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/common/how-to/resolve-react-template-issues/

Answer (score 2):

i solved this issue by calling

```
this.scheduleObj.addEvent(droppedItemData);
```

as in [creation-using-addevent-method](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/crud-actions/#creation-using-addevent-method) example.

In that example **addEvent** call seems not having any effect on the schedule (no appointemnt added) by i found that when calling it in the **onTreeDragStop**  (as in their [external-drag-drop](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/?_ga=2.33866724.452988640.1582879142-939992418.1581600757#/material/schedule/external-drag-drop)) after updating the **droppedItemData** with new matching data, it works,  and later on , in the **onActionBegin** (as in their [external-drag-drop](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/?_ga=2.33866724.452988640.1582879142-939992418.1581600757#/material/schedule/external-drag-drop)) an **event.requestType === 'eventCreate'** will be returned and there i could make the backend update too.